# Drag wpf window with thumb: can it be transparent?

Tags: wpf, slider, drag

I've been testing [Blu](http://www.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/blu/) and I noticed that I could drag the window. This window is transparent. I tried to do the same with a Thumb, but I don't know how to make it transparent. The rest of the window is transparent, but the thumb is not.

Is there any way to make the thumb transparent, or should I use another technique?

I use this event:

```
 private void DragThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, Canvas.GetLeft(this) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, Canvas.GetTop(this) + e.VerticalChange);
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can turn a thumb control invisible with the Opacity attribute.

Opacity="1" (full visible)

or

Opacity="0" (not visible)

Sample from my application

```
        <Thumb Name="myThumb"
               Width="10"
               Height="10"
               DragDelta="onDragDelta"
               DragStarted="onDragStarted"
               DragCompleted="onDragCompleted"
               Margin="5"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Opacity="1">

        </Thumb>
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but to drag a wpf window, all you need to type in the click event handler of a component on the form (or the form itsself) is:

```
this.DragMove();
```

There is no need to implement the dragging functionality yourself.

---

Update: small example: Create a window, place a button in it. Wire the MouseDown of the window and the Click of the button as:

```
    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.DragMove();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hey");
}
```

Works perfectly, you can drag the window, and the button continues to work...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom. I think that can be the solution. 

Tried it with a mousemove + leftbutton pressed in a grid and it worked partially. The buttons of the window stopped working. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Did a quick test, and everything is working over here... See my original answer for update with small example.

Comment: One thing is to detect mouse movement. Another thing is the actual Drag functionality, specifically the `VerticalChange` and `HorizontalChange` values from `DragDeltaEventArgs`. If you need to handle the drag, then `Thumb` is the way to go, setting its opacity to 0 as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, you can set control template of Thumb control as 'Transparent', as following snippet code:

```
<Canvas Background="LightGray">
    <Grid Canvas.Left="451" Canvas.Top="148" Width="120" Height="120" Background="Red">
        <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" Cursor="SizeAll"
               DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}">
            <Thumb.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>
        <Ellipse Fill="Pink" Height="100" Width="100" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    </Grid></Canvas>
```

DragDelta event:

```
private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var thumb = (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb)sender;
    var grid = (Grid)(thumb.DataContext);
    if (grid == null) return;
    var left = Canvas.GetLeft(grid);
    var top = Canvas.GetTop(grid);
    Canvas.SetLeft(grid, left + e.HorizontalChange);
    Canvas.SetTop(grid, top + e.VerticalChange);
}
```

[image]